# How can you produce a spectrum with He3 thermal neutron detector?

Tags: neutrons, particle-detectors

I'm looking to understand how Bonner Sphere System works. I understand the whole idea, but I'm lost about how a single sphere can produce a whole spectrum.

For instance with He3 thermal detector, the reaction is the following :
He3 + n -> H1 + H3 + 764 keV

H1 and H3 kinetic energies are both determined by conservation laws. So in the case of a perfect detector, we should systematically measure a peak with eventually a small width coming from neutron energy (thermal/few meV << 764 keV).

Then how are we able to reconstruct a continuous (convoluted/folded) spectrum from a single sphere if the measurement is acting like a counter from my understanding ? I'm missing something here but I don't understand what

Comment: The original design (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0029554X60900434) used a Li$^{6}$I crystal doped with Eu using the Li$^{6}$(n,$\alpha$)H$^{3}$ reaction, with the energetic $\alpha$ exciting the scintillator. You don't get a spectrum, you get a count of neutrons with little sensitivity change over a wide range of neutron energy.

Comment: So the apparent spectrum is coming solely from the neutron kinetic energy which slightly shift the energy measured from the peak ?

Comment: The point of the Bonner sphere is to get a nearly-energy-independent count of neutrons. If you want a spectrum you need to do something else.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand how multiple Bonner sphere work together. How is it possible to reconstruct a rather good spectrum (with poor energy resolution but overall rather correct) with only a neutron count from few spheres

Comment: Now that is a slightly different question. The classic Li$^{6}$(n,$\alpha$)H$^{3}$ reaction does have some energy dependence. Using different diameter Bonner spheres results in different amounts of downscattering of neutron energy. So, the slightly different count rates allows for a rough deconvolution of neutron energy.